# Other way to apply a color instead of SystemColors in order to avoid color changes when publishing to an older Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

First of all, sorry about the messy title...

I'll try my best to explain.

So.. I'm currently using for the BackColor property in Designer, the following:

```
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
```

When I publish the application and use in other machine (Older windows... different theme, etc..). The color that was defined before, its not the same.

My question is, is there another way to apply a color to avoid this kind of situation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Change it to another color. What's the problem?

Comment: I dont understand your problem. You set the background color to a system value, and that can off course be different on another windows. What exact do you want to do ?

Comment: Do you want the color to be what's the default on your dev pc or on the user's pc?

Comment: Imagine, I'm publishing the application in Windows Server 2012.
I'm making some QA Tests in another remote machine which curently has Windows Server 2008, and the colors are different in there

Comment: They say its about the Windows Theme, etc...
That's why I want to find a way to show the same color, even if the windows have different themes

Comment: You will have to store the colors you want and use those. For example with settings: `this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.myControlColor;`

Comment: this.BackColor = Color.Red; for example will always have red, no matter what theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is that you have selected a system color which will change depending on what system you run it on.

If you want to have colors stay the same no matter what system they are run on then you must explicitly set the color yourself.

```
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0); //Red
```

This will ensure the color stays red on any system.

Simply replace the FromArgb parameters with the correct RGB values for the desired color.

Comment: `this.BackColor = Color.Red;`does the same thing but shorter and more readable

Comment: @GuidoG You are correct. I chose the FromArgb method to illustrate how the color could be customized if need be.